# Avra valley aquifier region boundary

Tags: hydrology, reference-request

Attached is an image of the Avra valley in Southern Arizona, USA from

[Effects of Kriging and Inverse Modelling on Conditional Simulation of the Avra Valley Aquifier in Southern Arizona -- Clifton and Neuman](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1029/WR018i004p01215)

Two related questions

1. What is this `R{int}E-T{int}S` coordinate system? Is it US specific? Arizona specific? A reference and how to convert to a global system would be great.
2. Is there somewhere where I can find a shape file for the designated region? I'm assuming this particular example has been used in several studies.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: it is the position,if you google T12S R11E you will find maps of the area.

Comment: Questions for data are more suited for OpenData.SE, questions for coordinate systems are slightly more suited for GIS.SE. Two questions in one is not suited for SE in general.

Comment: T = township, R = range. Part of the PLSS, public land survey system.

Comment: Thank you both. @Erik get over yourself buddy, everyone else have a good day

Comment: @Nadiels Dude, I pointed you some places you might find more extensive help and you bitch at me? Really?